# Different animated pictures but only one control panel

Tags: package-options, animate

I have a beamer frame made up of different animated pictures which share the same time.

Is that a way to use the controls option in the animate package so that I can control all the animations at the same time? 
For example I may have 2 control panels simply doing

```
\begin{frame}[squeeze,label=MOV]
\frametitle{\centerline{Movie}}
\animategraphics[autoplay,loop,height=0.45\textheight,controls]{6}{vel/vel_}{01}{48}
\animategraphics[autoplay,loop,height=0.45\textheight,controls]{6}{sst/sst_}{01}{48}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 5):

You simply should generate one `animation`. For this you should use the `animateinline` environment. This environment is the manual command of `\animategraphics`.

For your case do this:

```
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop,controls]{6}
  \multiframe{48}{i=1+1}{%
      \includegraphics[height=.45\textheight]{vel/vel_\i}%
      \includegraphics[height=.45\textheight]{sst/sst_\i}
  }
\end{animateinline}
```

this should solve your problem.